# Flutter - Custom invoice view for the background

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, android-custom-view, invoice

I want to create the below-jagged look for the background for my invoice view. How do I achieve this? I am unable to recreate the same with the custom painter.

[image]

Your suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way if you don't want to use clippers, is to extract the jagged photo and use it as a background image in the container (or `Stack`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom clipper to achieve this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
            clipper: ZigZagClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 600,
              width: 500  ,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
  }
}

class ZigZagClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    double x = 0;
    double y = size.height;
    double increment = size.width / 20;

    while (x < size.width) {
      x += increment;
      y = (y == size.height) ? size.height * .95 : size.height;
      path.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper old) {
    return old != this;
  }
}
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

````
                    ClipPath(
                  clipper: ZigZagClipper(),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child:    CustomPaint(
                      painter: BorderPainter(color: ColorConstants.cardStrokeColor),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.sp),
                        child: [content],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )```
````

Use this zigzag clipper for the clipping and border painter for giving border

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';


class ZigZagClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double factor = 8.sp;
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(factor, 0);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(0, factor),radius: Radius.circular(8.sp),clockwise:false );
    // path.quadraticBezierTo(factor, 0, 0, factor);

    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    double x = 0;
    double y = size.height;
    double increment = size.width/50;

    while (x < size.width) {
      if(x+increment>size.width){
        x += size.width-x;
      }
      else{
        x += increment;
      }

      y = (y == size.height) ? size.height -increment : size.height;
      path.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    path.lineTo(size.width, factor);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width-factor, 0),radius: Radius.circular(8.sp),clockwise:false );
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper old) {
    return old != this;
  }
}
class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Color color;
  BorderPainter({ required this.color});
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double factor = 8.sp;
    Paint paint =  Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(factor, 0);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(0, factor),radius: Radius.circular(8.sp),clockwise:false );
   // path.quadraticBezierTo(factor, 0, 0, factor);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    double x = 0;
    double y = size.height;
    double increment = size.width/50;

    while (x < size.width) {
    if(x+increment>size.width){
      x += size.width-x;
    }
    else{
      x += increment;
    }

      y = (y == size.height) ? size.height -increment : size.height;
      path.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    path.lineTo(size.width, factor);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width-factor, 0),radius: Radius.circular(8.sp),clockwise:false );
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```